# Chosen option by onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm new in JavaScript, How can I get the `Fruit1` and `Fruit2` after I click the button `"Click me"`

For Example :
If I click the button, then choose 2 of fruits from the option. if I were to choose Apple and Banana then it should alert `"You choose Apple and Banana"`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourChoose() {
    alert("Now, let's choose 2 fruit do you like ?");  

    // code for i choose 2 fruits
    var Fruit1 = .....;
    var Fruit2 = .....;
    alert("You choose "+Fruit1+" and "+Fruit2)
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button name="clickme" onclick="yourChoose()" >click me </button><br/>
<a href=""> Apple </a><br/>
<a href=""> Banana </a><br/>
<a href=""> Coconut </a><br/>
<a href=""> Durian </a><br/>
<a href=""> ElderBerry </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example without jquery but with OOP :)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Fruiter(){ // Class that manage your fruits
    this.addFruit = function(fr){ // adding fruits
        if (this.fr1) {
            this.fr2 = fr; 
            alert("You choose "+this.fr1+" and "+this.fr2); // show messages when all fruits choosed
        } else {this.fr1 = fr;}
    }
    this.chooseFruit = function(fr){ // choosing fruits / reseting
        this.fr1 = null;
        alert("Now, let's choose 2 fruit do you like ?");      
    }
}
var f = new Fruiter();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button name="clickme" onclick="f.chooseFruit()" >click me </button><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="f.addFruit('Apple')"> Apple </a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="f.addFruit('Banana')"> Banana </a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="f.addFruit('Coconut')"> Coconut </a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="f.addFruit('Durian')"> Durian </a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="f.addFruit('ElderBerry')"> ElderBerry </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following javascript:

```
var fruit1="";      //set the global variables
var fruit2="";

function selectFruit(name){
    fruit2=fruit1;  //this will set the global variables
    fruit1=name;    //at only 1 point of time 2 fruits are selected!
}
```

The function selectFruit will make sure that only the latest 2 clicked fruits are stored

Next, change your links to the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectFruit('Apple')"> Apple </a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectFruit('Banana')"> Banana </a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectFruit('Coconut')"> Coconut </a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectFruit('Durian')"> Durian </a><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selectFruit('ElderBerry')"> ElderBerry </a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/guy777/8mJG5/

HTML :

```
<button id='btn' name="clickme">click me </button><br/>
<a href=""> Apple </a><br/>
<a href=""> Banana </a><br/>
<a href=""> Coconut </a><br/>
<a href=""> Durian </a><br/>
<a href=""> ElderBerry </a>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var a = $('a');
    var fruits = [];
    $.map(a, function(fruit) {
        fruits.push(fruit.text);
    });

    console.log(fruits);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this > http://fiddle.jshell.net/gUryq/3/

```
var fruits = { fruit1 : "", fruit2 : ""};
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    if(fruits.fruit1 == "" && fruits.fruit2 == "") {
        alert("Now, let's choose 2 fruit do you like ?");
    } else {
         alert("pls choose the other fruit first!");   
    }
});
```

... jquery in use!

Comment: it is work in fiddle, but when i copy from fiddle it doesnt work, what do you mean jquery in use?

Comment: you have to include jquery to your project <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: sry im newbie, what console do you mean?

Comment: browser console. press F12 in most browsers to open development console

Comment: im sry. i've edit my code in the question above, would you mind to correct where is the missing code?thanks

Comment: the fiddle solution works, so you have to find out whats wrong with your code! So you have to debug it... use F12